# db_query results by relevance

Tags: database

I want to query node titles by multiple word fragments and sort it by relevance.

Currently I have this but it does not sort:

```
$words = explode(' ', $text);

$db_or = db_or();

foreach($words as $word) {
   $db_or->condition('title', '%' . db_like($word) . '%', 'LIKE');
}

$result = db_select('node', 'n')
   ->fields('n', array('nid', 'title'))
   ->condition($db_or)
    ->execute();
```

I tried the following and it throws an exception:

```
$sql = "SELECT nid, title, MATCH (title) AGAINST " .
      "(':text' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS score " .
      "FROM node WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST " .
      "(':text1' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)";

$result = db_query($sql, array(':text' => $text, ':text1' => $text))
   ->execute();
```

Comment: What's the exception? Something along the lines of `Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list`? If so, run `ALTER TABLE node ADD FULLTEXT(title);` against the db (on a dev copy first, naturally)

Comment: @clive Yes, that was the exception and your suggestion fixed it. However, I'm still not closer to a solution as it gives me an empty result for words that I know are present. I think I'm on the wrong track with the SQL. I'm looking for behaviour where the more words are present in the title, the higher the ranking. I will most probably have to explore querying against search_api.